# Cors error when sending request to same domain

Tags: reactjs, frontend, cors

I have a frontend app made using react. It's running on say `https://frontend.example.com`. I am using `fetch` to send request to my backend server `https://backend.example.com`. But am getting cors error for this. I thought i don't have to set CORS(Access-Control-Allow-Origin in backend server) since same domain in used. Any idea what could be going wrong.

Comment: `frontend.example.com` and `backend.example.com` are clearly not the same domain. If your question is _"are sub-domains considered cross-origin?"_, the answer is **yes**

Comment: A common solution (other than implementing CORS support) is to proxy API requests via the frontend web server. Then you can just make path-only requests, eg `fetch("/api/something")`

Comment: Any link or place where I can look more into this approach.

Comment: Depends, what is your frontend web server? Searching for _"react reverse proxy api <insert web server>"_ should yield plenty of results

Comment: See the examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin